# Is there a hierarchy in CSS :not attributes

Tags: html, css

I tried the following code:

```css
main *:not(.second) {
  color: red;
}

main:not(#first) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h2>Deals</h2>
  <p id="first">This is the first line</p>
  <p class="second">French Horn</p>
  <p class="second">This is another line</p>
  <p>Bottle of water</p>
</main>
```

What I expected to happen was this: first the `main *:not(.second)` line would colour everything except for the elements with the second class red. And after that, `main:not(#first)` would would colour all the main elements without the id first as blue. This made me expect that all the lines would turn blue, because their parent, main, was assigned the color blue.

Now this did not happen, the first line became red, the second line too, the next two turned blue and the last one red again. How does this work exactly?

Comment: `main *:not(.second)` is stronger selector than `main:not(#first)` so everything is red but the elements with `class=second` - they are blue. Don't forget that `main:not(#first)` isn't the same as `main :not(#first)`.

Comment: Ah I get it, thanks. Is there a way to know which selectors are stronger than others, other than testing?

Comment: Sure - https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity